# Which manifolds admit symmetric tilings?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, symmetry, cw-complexes, polytopes

Let $M$ be a connected, boundaryless manifold. A *tiling* of $M$ is a [regular cellulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex) of $M$, and a tiling is *regular* (i.e. symmetric) if the group of self-homeomorphisms of $M$ that map cells to cells acts [transitively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Transitivity_properties) on the [flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(geometry)) of the cellulation. (Equivalently, the tiling is regular if the corresponding [abstract polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_polytope) is [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polytope).) Can we always find a regular tiling of $M$?

For example, the surface of a cube represents a regular tiling of the sphere $S^2$, and we can identify its opposite cells to get a regular tiling of [$\Bbb{RP}^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane). These examples generalize to higher dimensions (e.g. using a [regular 4-polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_4-polytope) to tile $S^3$) and arbitrary quotients of the polytope's symmetry group.

Another construction I've found is as follows: start with a self-dual regular 4-polytope like the [24-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-cell), inscribe in each (octahedral) cell its dual polyhedron (a cube), enlarge the inscribed duals slightly and truncate the resulting overlaps, joining the intersecting faces (squares truncated to octagons) along the truncation edges. These faces form a regular 2D tiling of a surface with a large genus. I think this procedure also generalizes to higher dimensions.

But is there a regular tiling of every 2D surface? Can we get every [spherical 3-manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_3-manifold)? I'm interested in any necessary or sufficient conditions on $M$ for the existence of a regular tiling.

Comment: I would suggest rewording your post so as not to depend on that very poor wikipedia page; otherwise, your question does not make sense.

Comment: @LeeMosher You mean the abstract polytope page? I agree that that page doesn't clearly define the topology associated with an abstract polytope, but I was hoping that part was clear enough (by analogy to abstract simplicial complexes, if you like). Is there something else about the question that doesn't make sense?

Comment: No, I do not think that part is clear enough.

Comment: @Karl To add to Lee Mosher's concern, the "analogy" with abstract simplicial complex doesn't make sense to me. For simplicial complexes, there is an obvious choice of topological space and attaching maps for each $k$-face (i.e. the solid simplex with the inclusion of the faces). No such object seems to exist for abstract polytopes, since the "boundary" of a $k$-face can be one of a variety of different $k-1$ manifolds for $k>2$. Is there a particular construction you had in mind?

Comment: I think I see what you mean. The "locally spherical" condition means that the facets and vertex figures are themselves topological spheres. Is that insufficient (or not clearly defined)? Do you think there's a better way to formulate the question?

Comment: @Karl You should try and write down the topology construction explicitly in the question; that might clear things up. As an alternative, you may want to look at *regular CW-complexes*, which are more commonly used in this context and seem similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Aha, thanks! It looks like regular CW-complexes correspond to locally spherical abstract polytopes in the desired way. I'll edit the post.

Comment: The standard CW decomposition of the torus into one vertex, two edges, and one face, is symmetric. You just need to show there is a homeomorphism exchanging the two loops, which will automatically exchange the corresponding flags.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Makes sense! That decomposition isn't regular in the CW sense, but the "2x2 version" with 4 faces, 4 vertices, and 8 edges seems to work. What about the 2-torus, I wonder?

Comment: Ha ha, oops. In my head I was thinking locally regular in the sense that the attaching map is locally a homeomorphism.

Comment: Do you explicitly consider non-compact manifolds? And when you say 2D surface, do you allow infinite genus? Or are we talking only about the sphere attached with finitely many handles and crosscaps?

Comment: @M.Winter an answer just for compact manifolds or surfaces of finite genus would be interesting! I still don't know whether the 2-torus has a symmetric tiling.